# Why does Kitchen not recognize my repository?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have a job that works fine in spoon, but I need to run it from outside for that I use kitchen, but it doesn't work, it doesn't recognize my repository that is in another machine.

The code that my kitchen has is this

```
Kitchen.bat /dir:"dir_mi_repository" /rep:"mi_repository" /job:mijob.kjb /level:Detailed /log:C:\logpentaho\logKettle.log 
pause 
exit
```

this is part of the run

```
... 2020 10:14:49 AM org.apache.karaf.main.Main$KarafLockCallback lockAquired
INFO: Lock acquired. Setting startlevel to 100
2020/06/08 10:14:50 - Kitchen - Logging is at level : Detailed
2020/06/08 10:14:50 - Kitchen - Start of run.
2020/06/08 10:14:50 - RepositoriesMeta - No repositories file found in the local directory: c:\Pentaho\repositories.xml
2020/06/08 10:14:50 - RepositoriesMeta - Reading repositories XML file: C:\Pentaho\.kettle\repositories.xml
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually create a BAT file and then schedule it by task scheduler. I do not see any login info for the repository, may be that's why it's not finding the jobs.

Below is a sample which I use for the BAT File.

"C:\data-integration\Kitchen.bat"/rep:"TEST" /job:"TEST_JOB" /dir:/TEST /user:admin /pass:admin

I am using the community edition. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to put the username and password to do it well

I had already tried putting the username and password, and it did not work, but it seems that there was a configuration error, because on the server it worked perfectly, adding the username and password.

Thank you